# Rename the default tables in asp.net identity 3 (dbo.ASPNetxxx) with Uniqueidentifier or int for IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I have created a new web application in ASP.Net Core 1.1, the default templates of ASP.Net identity 3 comes with `nvarchar(400)` or strings as the default data type for the "Id" fields.

I have changed the default `TKey` type from `nvarchar(400)` to `Uniqueidentifier` , Is there any way to change the default dbo.ASPNetxxx tables in asp.net identity to a custom name using the default code first approach?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer in a comment [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/780) and i would like to share it more organized here, Thanks to "Raffaele Garofalo" for answering this, I have copied the answer and added my 2 cents:

to rename the default tables in `asp.net identity 3` and changing the data type to `Uniqueidentifier`, use the following steps:

In ApplicationDbContext.cs:

Change the ApplicationDbContext or whatever you used to reflect this one:

Change the class to be:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
```

and the `OnModelCreating` method to be:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // Customizations
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("Users");
        i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });
    builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("Roles");
        i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<Guid>>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("UserRoles");
        i.HasKey(x => new { x.RoleId, x.UserId });
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("UserLogins");
        i.HasKey(x => new { x.ProviderKey, x.LoginProvider });
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("RoleClaims");
        i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("UserClaims");
        i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<Guid>>(i =>
    {
        i.ToTable("UserTokens");
        i.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
    });

}
```

To add a default Guid value for Users and Roles IDs:

```
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
        });

        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
        });
```

I have just removed the ASPNet extension from the names, you may add your custom table names. and you may replace `Guid` with `int` for integer IDs

In ApplicationUser.cs  i have created a Custom ApplicationUser class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
}
```

and a Custom ApplicationRole class

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
}
```

In Startup.cs under `ConfigureServices` method

Change your ASP.NET Core Startup according:

```
services
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


services
        .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Delete the content inside the Data/Migrations folder, but keep the Migrations folder there.

Now in the commands line (CMD), change the directory to the application root:

```
CD X:\ApplicationPathHere
```

If exist, Drop the existing DB because the schema can't be migrated from PK String to PK Guid

```
dotnet ef database drop -c ApplicationDbContext
```

Create the initial migration

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -c ApplicationDbContext
```

Create the database

```
dotnet ef database update
```

**Update**
For .Net Core 2.0 MVC project template,

You may get some errors in the `ManageController`, Just cast the Ids by adding `.ToString()`

and no need to pass int or GUID for:

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
```

just add

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
```